# How to load Bootstrap on wordpress home page only

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I have a wordpress site and added bootstrap to it. Now the bootstrap is messing with some of the stylings on another page and the only thing I needed the bootstrap is for some cards on the homepage. please is there a way I make the bootstrap work on the homepage only? **It is a static homepage, not a blog page**

This is the code I added to the functions.php below:

```
   function bootstrap_script() {
   wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/styles/bootstrap.min.css');
   wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');
    }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap_script');
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/

Comment: thank you very very much God bless you
It worked

How can I mark your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use is_front_page function, as mentioned by CBroe.

However, I don't think this is a good approach to include the whole bootstrap library just for styling some cards, as it won't favour your page speed by doing this.

My suggestion is to style those cards manually in your css, you can have a look at flex box in css to do that. It will improve your page speed as your homepage won't need to load the bootstrap library on page load.